# MySQL Query won't run past a certain point in the promise chain

Tags: node.js, mysql2

I'm pulling data from Amazon MWS and inserting it into a MySQL db. For some reason the MySQL commands stop running after a certain point in the promise chain.

A basic query stops working once we get to    .then(getInventoryDaysRemaining)

```
getUSInventory()
   .then(requestInventoryDaysRemainingReportId)
   .then(function() {
    db.query(`select 11111`, function(err, results) { 
        if (err) { 
            console.log(err);
        } else { 
            console.log(results);
        }
    });
   })
   .then(getInventoryDaysRemaining)
   .then(combineInventoryAndDaysRemaining)
   .then(pushCombinedUSInventoryToDatabase)
   .then(function() {
       console.log('Success!');
       process.exit();
   })
   .catch((err) => {
     console.log(err);
     process.exit();
});
```

I'd expect a basic MySQL query to run within any part of the chain but it stops once we get to    .then(getInventoryDaysRemaining)

Comment: `function(err, results)` doesn't return a promise.

Comment: I updated to do that and it will run fine. However if I put that same line of code further down the chain it will not log the results or an err.

Comment: Just make your function `async` and return something: `.then(async () => { // function body here which returns something }).then(...)`